# Flipping an image with JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to flip an image.  I have gotten the css to work using:

```
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
```

I am looking to apply this to an image but am unsure of the formatting.

I tried doing:
 `var flip = "-moz-transform: scaleX(-1),-o-transform: scaleX(-1),-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1),transform: scaleX(-1),filter: FlipH,-ms-filter: 'FlipH'";`

And then:
`$("#chicken").delay(scrolllen).fadeOut(0).css({ left: 2600 + "px" , top : 2370 + "px" + flip}).fadeIn(0).animate({ left: 1600 + "px" , top : 2370 + "px"}, 5000, 'linear');`
at a later point, but it doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: You are passing the [css function](http://api.jquery.com/css/) a javascript object with 2 properties, left and top.  Where 'top' is a big string `"2370px-moz-transform: scaleX(-1),-o-transform: scaleX(-1),-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1),transform: scaleX(-1),filter: FlipH,-ms-filter: 'FlipH'"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you trying do to something like this?

```
$('#image').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('flipped');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('flipped');
});
```

the css:

```
.flipped {
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -khtml-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kjGNW/)

Comment: Not quite, but .addClass and .removeClass will certainly do what I want much better I think.  If I .removeClass as it doesn't have that class, will it return an error or ignore it, do you know?

Comment: @Splatter It will be ignored, jQuery removeClass uses replace method and replaces given class name to " ", so it will just do nothing.

Comment: Both this and adeneo's is correct for what I need.  Marking this one correct because it was offered first.  Sorry adeneo(but I gave you +1!)

Answer (score 3):

I'd just use a class, like so:

```
.flipped {
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

Then just swap the class:

```
$("#chicken").delay(2000).fadeOut(1, function() {
    $(this).addClass('flipped').show()
           .animate({ left: 1600 + "px" , top : 2370 + "px"}, 5000, 'linear');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jb8DF/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're looking for.

I'm thinking perhaps it can be done without any JavaScript at all? If you're looking to flip along the X axis, with some animation?

### Flipping Image on Hover

**[JSFiddle: Image Flip on :hover](http://jsfiddle.net/Snv4B/1/)**

**For this demo, I had to place the image HTML into a wrapper `<div>`, because otherwise the `:hover` and the `scale()` changes conflict with one another in funky ways. You'll understand if you remove the wrapper `<div>`.**

**HTML**

```
<div class="flippy">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.flippy>img {
    /**/-moz-transform:scale(1,1);-webkit-transform:scale(1,1);
    transform:scale(1,1);
    /**/-webkit-transition:all 600ms ease;-webkit-transition:all 600ms ease;
    transition:all 600ms ease; }

    .flippy:hover>img {
        /**/-moz-transform:scale(-1,1);-webkit-transform:scale(-1,1);
        transform:scale(-1,1); }
```

If you need to control it with JavaScript, it should be easy enough to replace the `:hover` with another class, like `.flipped`, then do as you please in JS to activate it's flip state on and off.

//Chase.

### Flipping Image on Attribute (click-based demo)

**[jsFiddle: Image Flip on Attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseMoskal/sesZv/)**

In this demo, the image flips when is has the `flipped` attribute set.

**JavaScript:**

```
// Toggles the 'flipped' attribute on the <img> tag.
$('.flippy').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('flipped'))
        $(this).removeAttr('flipped');
    else $(this).attr('flipped','flipped');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
/* vendor-prefixes have been removed in this example */
/* We just change the scale based on the flipped attribute */
.flippy {
    transform:scale(1,1);
    transition:all 600ms ease; }

    .flippy[flipped] {
        transform:scale(-1,1); }
```

**HTML:** `<img class="flippy" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"/>` -- as you can see, we no longer need the `<div>` wrapper for this example, as the :hover conflicts are no longer an issue.

//Chase.

Comment: I don't wish to use hover at all.  This is to happen during an animation.

Comment: @Splatter -- I added another section and jsFiddle to my answer. This second demo animates the image to be flipped or unflipped based on the presence of a `flipped` attribute that can be easily added or taken away with jQuery.

Comment: @Splatter: Not even a +1? C'mon man! I don't get paid for this XD

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .transform-image {     
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
            transform: scaleX(-1);
            filter: FlipH;
            -ms-filter: "FlipH";
        }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#chicken").hover(function(){
           $(this).addClass("transform-image") },   
     function () {
           $(this).removeClass("transform-image");
         };
})
</script>
```