# Reflected-repeated background image with css or js?

Tags: css, background-image

Let's say I have this as an image;

[image: background image]

This is what I want to make background look like;

[image: result]

In words; I want to background image repeat but horizontally flipped on every repeat.

I am aware I can just put original image and horizontally flipped version side by side and use it. But this means doubling original image's size and if it is already big, this is not a solution.

Comment: If your issue is loading performance, use a linear-gradient combined with backgroud-size instead.

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer here : [Flipping an image with JS/Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694205/flipping-an-image-with-js-jquery) is basically what you're looking for, except that you'll need to replace the mouseover function with some kind of loop (depending on what language you're using) that adds a "flipped" class with a modulo